# Does your Galactic Readiness have any effect before the "end-game"?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I know that Galactic Readiness defines how the game will end, but does it have an effect on the rest of the game as well? For example, if I played a ton of multiplayer and got my readiness up to 100%, would the dialog change so that everyone was commenting on how well we were doing? Would the map or mission locations change at all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It changes a few things up to the ending. Like % of hammer that arrives on the surface and etc. Having certain people alive allows you to talk to them and makes a difference in endgame scenarios.

But other than that, readiness does nothing to change pre-endgame plot because your fleet power only matters when you use it.

Answer (score 1):

No, the only thing Effective War Assets change is the ending.  They are only taken into account when you start the mission Priority: Earth.

You could kinda/sorta say that having certain war assets changes the game - for instance, having Grunt or Jack survive ME2 gives you war assets *and* changes the game in certain situations, but this is kind of a stretch.